# Application.ontime fails when another workbook is open in "safe mode"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm ripping my hair out here ...

I have an Excel worksheet, that I use for registering time used on different tasks. In the worksheet, I start a "clock" that runs as long as I'm working on a task, in increments of 10 seconds.
This works just fine, as long as there is not another workbook open, that is in safe-mode (I.e. opened from a weblocation, and "enable editing" not activated).
If this is the case, the timer fails with...

```
"Run-time error '1004':
Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed.
```

AND...

- If the workbook in safemode is the "last workbook to have focus", before going to another window on the computer, the macro will fail.
- If the workbook that contains the macro is the last Excel window to have focus, before going to another window on the computer, even if there is also another workbook open in "safemode", the macro does NOT fail.
- If another workbook is the "last excel to have focus", but is open in "edit enabled" mode, the macro will NOT fail.

My code:

```
Dim TimerActive As Boolean

Sub Start_Timer()
    TimerActive = True
    Timer
End Sub

Sub Stop_Timer()
    TimerActive = False
End Sub

Sub Timer()
    If TimerActive Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Register_time").Range("InputTimeTo").Value = Time
        ThisWorkbook.Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Timer"
    End If
End Sub
```

When the macro fails, the debugger highlights the line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Timer"
```

I would like to somehow work around this, so that the macro works "in the background", even if another workbook has focus (safemode or not), or if a completely different program has focus.

Note: I can't have the workbook with the macro gain focus, when the clock needs to update, as this would mean that I would leave the program that I'm working in.
It would, however, be ok, if the clock was not updated, until I choose to set focus back to the worksheet where the clock is displayed.

Anyone?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the active workbook. try using `workbooks("mainBook.xlsm")`  ... or whatever the name of your workbook is

Answer (score -1):

Try to type this code before the "Ontime" line:

*On Error Resume Next*
*ThisWorkbook.Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Timer"*

This avoid the unexpected behavior.

Best,