# Application functions doesn't work when you open another file in "safe mode"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that runs every x minutes with Application.OnTime.
The problem is that if I open a different workbook and get the yellow ribbon thing asking if I want to edit the file (or macro safety warning) the Application.OnTime stops working.

There is another question quite similar to mine here:
[Application.ontime failes, when another workbook is open in "safe mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041163/application-ontime-failes-when-another-workbook-is-open-in-safe-mode)
But the answer is not really an answer since that will just skip the line and make the code not run OnTime.

Is there anything that can be done to still allow Application.OnTime to run even if I have another file open in safe mode?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but do you get the same problem if you work in 2 different instances of Excel?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns As far as I know. That is what I get. I use Win 10 and it opens two windows down there. But if that translates to two different instances, not sure... How can I know?

Comment: To open a new instance of Excel, hold key ALT while you click on the icon to open Excel. That new window should be a new instance (you can check it out with `application.Workbooks.Count`). Maybe if you open that workbook with macros in a different instance of excel, you can just leave it there working, and work with the rest of your files in a different instance.

Comment: [4 Ways to Open Multiple Instances of Excel](https://excelgorilla.com/excel/general/open-multiple-instances-excel/)

Comment: Did you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475195/11167163)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns That actually works. But it's not a good solution since this file is used by many people at work. That should mean everyone needs to remember to ALT + open a file all the time or use the regedit way. Not sure everyone will remember or know how to regedit, or even if our computers can be edit the registry at that place. I know some places of the registry is blocked (such as the num-lock fix thing)

Comment: @Dorian That is not an answer. That as much of an answer as "turn off your computer to not get an error", it just masks the problem as I pointed out in my question.

Comment: @Andreas Thats a really interesting question, I upvoted your post and hope someone can help ! I am also interested by this answer

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I think you should write out your method as an answer to this question. I wont accept it but I will upvote it. It's not the method I'm looking for but others may be helped by it.

Comment: VBA works in each instance the same way. IF you open a file and block VBA, you are blocking VBA for all files opened in that instance. So the only option I see is that you need to open that conflictive workbook on a new instance, (and rest of files in default instance, not ALT key, just the conflictive one) so it won't be affected by other blocks of files.

Comment: @Andreas Let me try to get a workarounf. If i fail, I'll post my previous comment as answer

Comment: Did you try disabling the automation security before opening the file? Check [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888338/4934172) for sample code and check Tim's answer there for more information.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed No. It will only solve the problem if it's macro safety warning and if the file is opened with VBA. Normally the problem is the safe mode from files (without macro) opened from web or emails.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution here is opening that conflictive workbook in a different instance of Excel, so it won't be affected by other files.

To manually open a new instance of Excel, hold key ALT and click on the Excel icon. But in your case, if several people are using the file, then everybody needs to do that.

I've been looking around about creating a BAT file that opens that file in a new instance, but I'm totally noob about ms-dos commands so I'm posting this answer and hoping somebody can help.

To create a BAT FILE is really easy: just create a TXT, type the commands, save it and change file extension to BAT.

Be aware that I'm using my PC paths, so you need to adapt it to your paths. I've tried a lot of things but can't manage it to work it out:

1. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE"` will open Excel **in a new instance**.
2. `start "excel.exe" "C:\filepath\yourfile.xlsx"` will open the file but in **active instance**. IF there is no instance, it will create a new one, but this does not work as you need it
3. `"filepath\yourfile.xlsm"` will do the same than step 2

So I've been not able to find the exact commands. But I'm pretty sure there must be a way that a BAT file opens a new Excel instance (like in step 1) and opens the file in that instance.

About your macro, another shot in the dark, but you posted *I have a workbook that runs every x minutes with Application.OnTime* don't know how many times do you need to execute it, but maybe with [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) you could automate the process, because Task Scheduler got an option to open files in new instances.

Sorry, but could not find the exact commands. I'm able to open Excel in a new instance, (step 1) and I'm able to open a specific file, but I'm not able to combine both of them.

Hope somebody can help with that part, so you can create a BAT file to execute that conflictive workbook in a different instance just by double clicking on that BAT file (so everybody won't need to remember about the ALT thing)

**WORKAROUND 2:** Other way would be executing that Excel file but from a different APP, so you can create a new instance of Excel from VBA. I made a simple Word file that creates and opens an Excel file in a new instance, so you can work with rest of Excel files. The code must be in the event `Document_Open`.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Visible = False
Dim ExcelAPP As Object
Dim ThisWB As Object
Set ExcelAPP = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelAPP.Visible = False
Set ThisWB = ExcelAPP.Workbooks.Open("filepath\yourfile.xlsm")
ThisWB.Close False
DoEvents
ExcelAPP.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Visible = True
Application.Quit False
End Sub
```

So just by opening this word file, your Excel File would be executed in a new instance and not visible.

**KNOWN FAILS:** This way is good if you already have an Excel instance opened, but if there is no Excel file opened (you close all of them), you execute this code, and then open an Excel File, the Excel file will be opened in that invisible instance, so it's not perfect.

Comment: Task scheduler will start Excel but not run the macro, unless the macro auto runs and saves it self and closes it self. Possible. But keeping the file open is probably easier. The macro runs between 2 and 8 minutes apart, it's random to make sure it's random who will do the slow task, update the database sheet. If I understnd your answer opening a new instance of this file is great. But what happens if I close all other files and only keep this file open. Then open a new file without ALT, Shouldn't that file open in the active instance (the problem file)?

Comment: Yes, if the only active instance of Excel is this one, and you open new normal excel file, it will be opened in this instance, due to being the only one available. If your file needs to be executed each 2-8 minutes, I'm afraid the best way is just keeping a PC turned on for that macro, and nobody uses that pc, because you are executing all the time the macro. Unless you dou the ALT thing or modify the registry, ofc.

Comment: Updated answer with another workaround, but not perfect >.<

Comment: Yes that would be the best option to have  a computer dedicated to this task. But IT-department says no. All accounts must be personal, meaning no generic windows accounts and computers are auto locked after a few minutes. That is why we use a database sheet to gather what everyone has managed to get and then that data can be used.